# How can I tell what version of the dBASE format a .dbf file is?

Tags: file-format, dbf

I have a variety of dbf files I am currently working with and it would be helpful for me to know the exact version of the dBASE format they are in, e.g. dBASE III, IV, 5.0, etc.

Is there a way to determine this?

Comment: you already know they are dBase and not foxpro files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is on the first byte:

According to these [two](http://www.clicketyclick.dk/databases/xbase/format/dbf.html#DBF_NOTE_1_TARGET) [links](http://www.dbase.com/KnowledgeBase/int/db7_file_fmt.htm), use a hex viewer and read the first byte.